# what does " ...:" mean in Ipython console anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, export-to-csv

I am trying to print a dataframe into a csv directly from Ipython Console, but I get this symbol and then nothing "   ...:". **What does the symbol mean?**

**Is there anyway I can force my csv to print ?**

Code:

```
import ET_Client
import pandas as pd


AggreateDF = pd.DataFrame()

try:

    debug = False
    stubObj = ET_Client.ET_Client(False, debug)

    print '>>>BounceEvents'
    getBounceEvent = ET_Client.ET_BounceEvent()
    getBounceEvent.auth_stub = stubObj    
    getResponse1 = getBounceEvent.get()
    ResponseResultsBounces = getResponse1.results
    Results_Message = getResponse1.message
    print "This is orginial " + str(Results_Message) 
    #print ResponseResultsBounces

    i = 1
    while (Results_Message == 'MoreDataAvailable'):
        if i > 5: break
        print Results_Message
        results1 = getResponse1.results
        i = i + 1
        ClientIDBounces = []
        partner_keys1 = []
        created_dates1 = []
        modified_date1 = []
        ID1 = []
        ObjectID1 = []
        SendID1 = []
        SubscriberKey1 = []
        EventDate1 = []
        EventType1 = []
        TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1 = []
        BatchID1 = []
        SMTPCode = []
        BounceCategory = []
        SMTPReason = []
        BounceType = []

        for BounceEvent in ResponseResultsBounces:
            ClientIDBounces.append(str(BounceEvent['Client']['ID']))
            partner_keys1.append(BounceEvent['PartnerKey'])
            created_dates1.append(BounceEvent['CreatedDate'])
            modified_date1.append(BounceEvent['ModifiedDate'])
            ID1.append(BounceEvent['ID'])
            ObjectID1.append(BounceEvent['ObjectID'])
            SendID1.append(BounceEvent['SendID'])
            SubscriberKey1.append(BounceEvent['SubscriberKey'])
            EventDate1.append(BounceEvent['EventDate'])
            EventType1.append(BounceEvent['EventType'])
            TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1.append(BounceEvent['TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID'])
            BatchID1.append(BounceEvent['BatchID'])
            SMTPCode.append(BounceEvent['SMTPCode'])
            BounceCategory.append(BounceEvent['BounceCategory'])
            SMTPReason.append(BounceEvent['SMTPReason'])
            BounceType.append(BounceEvent['BounceType'])

        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ClientID': ClientIDBounces, 'PartnerKey': partner_keys1,
                       'CreatedDate' : created_dates1, 'ModifiedDate': modified_date1, 
                       'ID':ID1, 'ObjectID': ObjectID1,'SendID':SendID1,'SubscriberKey':SubscriberKey1,
                       'EventDate':EventDate1,'EventType':EventType1,'TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID':TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID1,
                       'BatchID':BatchID1,'SMTPCode':SMTPCode,'BounceCategory':BounceCategory,'SMTPReason':SMTPReason,'BounceType':BounceType})
        #print(df1['ID'].max())
        AggreateDF = AggreateDF.append(df1)   
        print(AggreateDF)          
        #print df1
        df_masked1 = df1[(df1.EventDate > "2016-02-20") & (df1.EventDate < "2016-07-25")]
```

Comment: Add your code to your question. We can't help you with so little information. It is also a good idea to give an example of your desired result, and the actual result.

Comment: It means the output is truncated, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html

Comment: @HolyDanna must have missed adding code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thank you for the link will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Display Sizing

When `pandas` is printing to the console in iPython/Jupyter, it uses `...` to show that there is data in-between rows of the data displayed on the output.  This is useful when the data is to large to print every single value.  This is the default behavior unless you override the display options.

From [Frequently Used Options](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#frequently-used-options)

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7,2))
 pd.set_option('max_rows', 7)
 df
```

---

```
          0         1
0  0.469112 -0.282863
1 -1.509059 -1.135632
2  1.212112 -0.173215
3  0.119209 -1.044236
4 -0.861849 -2.104569
5 -0.494929  1.071804
6  0.721555 -0.706771
```

---

```
pd.set_option('max_rows', 5)
df
```

---

```
           0         1
0   0.469112 -0.282863
1  -1.509059 -1.135632
..       ...       ...
5  -0.494929  1.071804
6   0.721555 -0.706771

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```